# How to properly generate and call dataframes in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to to use a for loop to generate some new dataframes that are the subset of a specific dataframe and then modify those with the folowing code:

```
for(i in 2011:2017) {
      name <- paste("DF", i, sep = ".")
      assign(name, DF[DF$t==i,])
      DF2.[[i]] <- DF.[[i]] %>% group_by(Mes) %>% complete(Comuna = cms) %>% fill(t, .direction = "up")
}
```

where I know that:

```
for(i in 2011:2017) {
   name <- paste("DF", i, sep = ".")
   assign(name, DF[DF$t==i,])
}
```

works as it generates the dataframes for the years 2011 to 2017.

I also know the code:

```
DF2.(year) <- DF.(year) %>% group_by(Mes) %>% complete(Comuna = cms) %>% fill(t, .direction = "up")
```

works as it generate the rows I need. "(year)" is not part of the code, just to explain it's used on the resulting dataframes.

I've tried many ways to call the resulting dataframes [i], [[i]], using the assign code, but I always get the same error:

```
Error in group_by(., Mes) : object 'DF.' not found
```

So I'm looking for a workaround that allows me to use the fourth line of code or the proper way to call a dataframe on a for loop in this context or a document to fully understand the loops syntax.

I've found many similar questions or loop examples in R (or code) related sites, but I still can't understand the loop's syntax.

Thanks,

Comment: You can't access a data.frame named `DF.2011` via `DF.[[i]]` for `i == 2011`. You could use `get` combined with some `paste` function. but ssing this kind of dynamic naming is bad style. Consider storing your data.frames in a (named) `list` instead. This saves you from a lot of trouble and keeps your enviroment clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Martin Gal says, a list is a better way to go:

```
library(dplyr)

# Empty list to hold results
ll <- list()

for(i in 2011:2017) {
  ll[[paste0("DF.", i)]] <- DF %>%
    filter(t == i) %>%
    group_by(Mes) %>%
    complete(Comuna = cms) %>%
    fill(t, .direction = "up")
}
```

In this case, each list element is a dataframe. You can access these dataframes by name, e.g. `ll[["DF.2011"]]`